# How to filter by name of ReferenceProperty's model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following 3 classes:

```
class Locality(db.Model):
  location = db.ReferenceProperty()

class Organisation(db.Model):
  locality = db.ReferenceProperty(Locality)

class Position(db.Model):
  locality = db.ReferenceProperty(Locality)
```

Locality.location property is reference to Organisation or Position object.
I need to filter by Locality and get all entries with reference to Organisation.

I already tried, but it won't work:

```
Locality.all().filter("location =",Organisation)
```

Any advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution based on PolyModels:

```
class Locality(polymodel.PolyModel):
  { geo properties here }

class Organisation(Locality):
  title = db.StringProperty()

class Position(Locality):
  title = db.StringProperty()
```

To get all organisations filtered by geo properties:

```
Organisation.all().filter({by geo properties of Locality model})
```

To get all localities (organisations + positions) filtered by geo properties:

```
Locality.all().filter({by geo properties of Locality model})
```

I guess, my initial explanation was very unclear. Sorry for that. And thank you all, for your advices. They were very useful.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
Locality.all().filter("location =", Organisation)
```

You should be passing in an instance of Organisation rather then the class itself, e.g.:

```
org = Organisation.get(some_org_key)
Locality.all().filter("location =", org)
```

Comment: Drew, thank you for answer. Yes, I saw this solution before. In this case I will get list of Locality referenced to a single Organisation. It can be improved in the following way: Locality.all().filter("location IN", Organisation.all().fetch(1000)), but I need to avoid fetch on this stage.

Comment: @Thor Why do you want to do that? That would just return a locality that has any organization at all. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Locality(db.Model):
  location = db.ReferenceProperty()

class Organisation(db.Model):
  locality = db.ReferenceProperty(Locality,collection_name='org')

class Position(db.Model):
  locality = db.ReferenceProperty(Locality,collection_name='pos')
```

now each and every locality object will have an loc attribute, which is nothing but an collection of Organisation.

To know more about modeling , go through this [blog](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/er-modeling-with-google-app-engine.html)

Answer (score 0):

I like Abdul's approach better than Drew's answer (although he answers your specific question correctly).  I don't know all the moving parts here but I suspect you want to model this a bit differently, perhaps using PolyModel, and some de-normalization.  I mean just looking at the relationships of these four classes, I see a lot of de-refrencing going on just for simple queries.